# How does Java VM allocate memory?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, jvm, linked-list

I am wondering how does Java VM allocate memory?
does JAVA allocate memory in the physical memory in our computer?
Right now I am trying to compare two data structures, linked list and array taking caution in terms of page fault, and cache hit/miss, to see the performance of each data structure in really low level(harddisk, memory, cache level)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this answers your question but [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/) has a good article about how JVM uses native memory on Windows / Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Java allocates continous memory from the OS on startup.  Once it has the memory it needs for the heap, it controls how memory is allocated.

Memory in Java is allocated continously so it highly likely that each object will apear in memory in the order it is allocated. (But this is not guaranteed)
Additionally if the object survives a minor collection, it is likely to be copied in the order the objects are discovered. (again not guaranteed)

Personally I would use an ArrayList if you expect random access, and LinkedList if you want to insert anywhere but the end of the List.

Java performs very badly is any of it is swapped to disk. I would suggest ensuring it is small enough to fit into memory at all times.  Its cache behaviour is not easily controlled and the best thing you can do is experiment with how the JVM optimises your code and its caching behaviour.